# Should I use logging in a C++ library

Tags: c++, debugging, logging

So I am asking about a general advise on the topic. I'm developing a C++ library for numerical computation, however trough development I found it useful for debugging when there is an issue to have a flag which to enables some form of logging done so that I can inspect what is going wrong. My question is what are the acceptable standards on this? Should I define some macro for DEBUG so that if its not define no DEBUGs happen? Should I use a logging library and log stuff.

Comment: _"what are the acceptable standards on this"_ - There are no standards for this.

Comment: Okay, let me paraphrase - what are design choices which are considered good, or well if not just any advise that you would give based on experience. I have never done such development and am genuinely looking for some advice.

Comment: Primarily opinion-based: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: IMO I think a library should report errors, throw exceptions and leave the logging up to the client code. Certainly have macro-driven debugging that won't appear in the release version of the library for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments above mention there is no general answer to your question - it depends on the situation as well as personal opinion. Personally I mostly use

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// logging here
#endif
```

blocks in my code (in combination with some specialised `DEBUG_PRINT` macros of mine which print additional information such as a variable's name and type, etc). Then I simply pass a `-DDEBUG` flag to the compiler to globally enable all the DEBUG logging. (I normally use cmake so I have this flag passed by default in all debug builds) I don't know whether this is considered an "acceptable" practice or not - it has worked well for me.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this kind of advise. Do you use any other debug library, or do you just use some simple defined debug macros. I'm interested if there is easy way of doing this, so that I can control which classes DEBUG statements get printed, as since there are a lot of things going on showing all DEBUG messages might be not too good

Comment: It depends on the project. I mostly use these two macros: `#define DEBUG_PRINT(A) std::cout << #A << ": " << (A) << std::endl;` and `#define PRINT_TYPE_INFO(A) std::cout <<  #A << ": "<< boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr< decltype((A)) >().pretty_name() << std::endl;` The first prints the variable's name and it's value and the second an object's type. In certain cases I also use `boost::logging` system to have debug messages appended into some file along with timestamps etc. With the latter you can define priorities (fatal, error, etc) and globally enable/disable messages according to it.